# Creating multiple buffers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I'm new to QGIS and have no programming skills.

Is there an easy/uncomplicated way to create multiple buffers around a line feature?

Answer (score 10):

The way to do it without plugins is use **Batch Processing** from **Processing toolbox**.

Find **Fixed distance buffer** algorithm, and execute is as batch process (*right click --> Execute is as batch process*).
[image]

In the batch processing window you can do different settings on different parameters (one layer - different distances, same distance - different layers etc.).

[image]

You can also autofill your output file names depend on parameters.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Documentation:
[Batch processing QGIS manual](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html)

Comment: When doing a multi-distance buffer, you would normally like the result to be a layer of non-overlapping buffer zones (and with an attribute that indicates the distance(s) defining the zone.  Can this be achieved using the process you have described?

Answer (score 8):

Now possible with the Multi Ring Buffer:

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Multi_Ring_Buffer/

In version 0.1 it only works on the layer that is selected in the TOC when you launch the tool but feature requests can be posted to the issue tracker:

https://github.com/HeikkiVesanto/QGIS_Multi_Ring_Buffer/issues

Answer (score 3):

The *Multi-distance buffer* plugin returns a polygon dataset with multiple non-overlapping buffer zones and a *distance* attribute that identifies the different zones. The zones are dissolved, and none of the attributes of the original dataset are preserved.

Answer (score 2):

Not as far as I know. I think you'll have to make the buffers in separate shapefiles (Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Buffers). Nick.

Comment: Thanks Nick, thats what I ended up doing, just a shame it isn't a one step move...yet!

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for visual buffering (not creating the buffers as accurate features), you can utilize the 'new symbology' and build up symbol layers, basing their size on map units. Click 'Change..' under the symbol to add layers. Also, look into rule-based symbols for logical control over what gets visually buffered.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. I found that you can do multiple ring buffers in [OpenJump](http://www.openjump.org/).

Which is another open source GIS and may be suitable for your requirements.