# Is there a tool to buffer features with more than one distance value in GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis, vector, buffer

I´m looking for a tool like **Multiple-Ring-Buffer** in ArcGIS, but for GRASS GIS to be able to buffer with different distances but only having to start the process once.

Comment: Could you use a shell script (run GRASS in text only mode using -text), or am I misunderstanding the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The little-known [OpenJump](http://www.openjump.org/) GIS (Open Source)  has a  Multi-Ring-Buffer function since the version 1.3 (1.6.3 now) and you can still do that with a script (Bash or Python) in GRASS GIS (look at [Is it possible to create multiple buffers using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22752/is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-buffers-using-qgis/32040#32040)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I´m looking for a tool that can be used outside any GIS-application in a python script. That´s why I´m using GRASS. Would that be possible with the OpenJump tools as well?