# Buffer regions how do you get only a certain distance from the vector

Tags: qgis

Currently have a few vector lines that i want to create buffers for e.g. 10m, 20m,30m etc. I have created buffers but its not what i was aiming for, I want to see how another vector layer is affected. For more specifics I want to have a buffer region that goes from 0-10, 10-20, 20-30 etc but currently i have buffers that start from the original vector so its ending up as 0-10, 0-20, 0-30. Is it possible to create buffers for certain distances away from the interested vector or not? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22752/creating-multiple-buffers-using-qgis but it's a few years old so there may be different/better solutions now. A keyword phrase to search on is multi-ring buffers.

Answer (score 6):

In QGIS 3.4.5 you can use `Multi-ring buffer (constant distance)` in which you can specify the number of rings (in your case 3) and the distance is 10, if your projection supports meter unit, as you can see below:

[image]

You can find the tool from `Processing toolbox -> Vector geometry -> Multi-ring buffer (constant distance)`.

Here is the output:

[image]

and to make sure each buffer zone starts from the end of the previous buffer zone, I turned off zone 0-10 m:

[image]